# Unable to scrape certain elements with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape a product page using pupeteer and Cheerio. [(this page)](https://stockx.com/nike-air-force-1-low-white-07)

I'm using a data id to scrape the title and image. The problem is that the title never gets scraped while the image does every time.

I've tried scraping the title by class name but that doesn't work either. Does this have something to do with the specfic website I'm trying to scrape? Thank you.

my code:

```
    // Load cheerio
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);
    
    /* Scrape Product Page */
    const product = [];
    
    // Title
    $('[data-testid="product-name"]').each(() => {
       product.push({
         title: $(this).text(),
       });
    });
    
     // Image
     $('[data-testid="product-detail-image"]').each((index, value) => {
          const imgSrc = $(value).attr('src');
           product.push({
             image: imgSrc,
           });
      });
```

Comment: What's the point of using cheerio and Puppeteer? If the site is dynamic, use Puppeteer all the way, otherwise use cheerio all the way. Where is `data` coming from exactly?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. `data` is the pages' html that is collected from pupeteer.

Comment: Right, but since Puppeteer is interacting with the page dynamically, when `data` is collected is important. You're basically snapshotting the page in a particular state, then dumping it into a static HTML parser (again, sort of pointless since Puppeteer can already extract the data...). If the elements aren't there when you snapshot the DOM, cheerio won't see them either, so I'd edit your post to show all relevant code.

Comment: Ah that makes sense as to why it wasn't grabbing the title. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, there's almost no use case I can think of that makes sense with both Puppeteer and Cheerio at once. If the data is static, use Cheerio alongside a simple request library like Axios, otherwise use Puppeteer and skip Cheerio entirely in favor of native Puppeteer selectors.

One other potential reason to use Puppeteer is if your requests library is being blocked by the server's robot detector, as appears to be the case here.

This script worked for me:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const url = "https://stockx.com/nike-air-force-1-low-white-07";
  await page.goto(url);

  const nameSel = '[data-testid="product-name"]';
  await page.waitForSelector(nameSel, {timeout: 60000});
  const name = await page.$eval(nameSel, el => el.textContent);

  const imgSel = '[data-testid="product-detail-image"]';
  await page.waitForSelector(imgSel);
  const src = await page.$eval(imgSel, el => el.src);

  console.log(name, src);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

Comment: The nice thing about cheerio is that the methods aren't async, so you can set a breakpoint and test getting the data, which you can't do with $eval.